# AJAX works locally; 404 on production

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I have a Laravel application that works perfectly locally, but every AJAX call returns 404 when hosted. I'm unsure if this is from a sever config error, a missing php.ini setting, or something else? I've included an example of a failing call.

AJAX/JQ:

```
var url = "/final-review";
$("#review_note_text").change(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });

  $('#review_note_loader').show();

  var formData = {
    note_text: $('#review_note_text').val(),
  };

  var type = "POST";
  var reviewNoteUrl = url + '/review-note';

  $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: reviewNoteUrl,
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      $('#failure-message-review').hide();
      $('#success-message-review p').html("Saved successfully" + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>');
      $('#success-message-review').show();
      $('#review_note_loader').removeClass("halted-loader").hide();
    },
    error: function (data) {
      $('#review_note_loader').addClass("halted-loader");
      $('#failure-message-review p').html("Something went wrong, your record was not updated. <strong>Error Code: " + data.status + "</strong>" + '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>');
      $('#failure-message-review').show();
    }
  });

});
```

My Corresponding Route:

`Route::post('final-review/review-note', 'FinalReviewController@update_review_note');`

Controller Function

```
  public function update_review_note(Request $request){

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
      'note_text' => 'nullable|string',
    ]);

    $note = \App\ReviewNote::create([
      'note_text' => $request->get('note_text'),
      'author' => Auth::user()->name,
      'created_at' => now()
    ]);

    return Response::json($note);
  }
```

**SOLVED:**

I had to change the "url" var in my blade template to be:
`var url = "{{ url('/final-review') }}";`

In my AJAX I was defining "url" as "/final-review", which led to a route of "foobar.com/final-review/params" what I really needed was "foobar.com/app-name/final-review/params".

Testing locally, I did not have "app-name" in my URL.

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: @CameronHurd It produces no laravel logs or IIS logs. Should I be looking somewhere else as well?

Comment: do you have a url rewrite in place? if not the call will most likely have to be `/index.php/final-review/review-note/`